# Can anyone explaine why "git status" shows files as modfied when running under a share on linux?

Tags: windows, linux, git

The files are hosted on a windows machine,, and i was wondering if i cold use my Linux box to manage git, so i mounted the share. And then i see that when doing git status all the files shows as modified, and when trying to push from this share it wont accept my key.

**The image is from same snapshot, same folder at same time.**

Linux  --------------------------------------------------------winGitBash

[image]

Comment: What did `git diff` say the modification was in those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This blog post](http://gergap.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/git-crlf-hook/) explains it quite nicely. Basically it is good idea to set:

> git config --global core.autocrlf true

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked your `crlf` settings on the two machines? One may be re-creating the files as CRLF (Windows) while the other has just LF endings. That would be sufficient for the 'modified' status.

Don't forget your personal settings as well as the repo settings.

Answer (score 1):

How git behaves on newline depends on several configurations:

- core.eol
- core.autocrlf
- .gitattributes file

For you situation, I suspect below may be the reason.

- In your git "database"(.git), all text files are stored with newline `LF`.
- Your local repo is cloned under Windows, during checkouting git converts
  `LF` into `CRLF`.
- When you do `git status` under Linux/cygwin, since the "cygwin git" thinks it is working
  under "*inux" environemnt, so that that git thinks the local repo are supposed to
  checkout text files with `LF`. When it actually finds `CRLF`, it thinks that `CRLF`
  is changed from `LF`, so git reports they are modified.

To verify this(not fix this), you can do:

```
# under linux 

# save your change
git stash

# delete working directory
git rm --cached -r .

# re-checkout
git reset --hard
```

And run `git status` again, you will/should see the output reports no modification.

References:

[Mind the end of your line](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)